# How can I use the value of prev HTTP Request to the next HTTP Request in jMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I'm newbie in jMeter and I'm working with it.
I have one Thread Group which consists of two Loop Controllers.
In 1st Loop Controller, there's a HTTP Request which contains body data

```
{ ..., "var1": "var-${__RandomString(10,1234567890abcdefg)}", ... }
```

In 2nd Loop Controller, there's also another HTTP Request that contains var1, and I want to asssign this var1 with same value as the prev var1 in the 1st Loop Controller.

I have tried use User Defined Variables, but it generated same value for another Thread Groups, I want generate different value of var1 for each Thread Group.

Can anyone help me what should I do to make it works? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Add Post Processors --> Regular Expression Extractor to the Http Request which you want to fetch the variable named `var1`.

[image]

As the above picture is shown use `"var1": "(.+?)",` as Regular Expression. The `(.+?)` part defines that Hey! Regular Expression Extractor, please fetch for me whatever is between `"var1": "` and `",`, which you'll find in the response content. So `var-${__RandomString(10,1234567890abcdefg)}` would be fetched into a variable named `Var1` (Because you defined `Var1` as the Reference name.

Then, in the Http Request where you want to access that variable, use `${Var1}` in order to send the value of `Var1` variable as a request parameter. Something like the picture below

[image]

Note that the last value in the loop will be saved in `Var1`. If you want to save all values in the first loop in order to use those in the second loop,There's many way to do that.

You can add a Counter from Config Element to the first loop Controller and define for example `loopCounter` as the reference name for it. Fill the start and increment fields with `0` and `1`.

[image]

Then change the regular expression to `Var${loopCounter}`

[image]

In the next loop's Http Request you can access these variables with `${Var1}`, `${Var2}` and ...

Comment: Hi @BzH, thank you for the answer, I have tried your suggestion but it did not work, I checked the value of var1 in the 2nd Loop Controller is parameter ${var1}

Comment: @FergaDipa that's because you define `${Var1}` (with capital letter of `V`)in Regular Expression and refer to `${var1}` (with small letter of `v`) in Http Request

Answer (score 0):

Just change your [__randomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function to look like:

```
${__RandomString(10,1234567890abcdefg,var1)}
```

it will overwrite `${var1}` with random generated value so you'll get the same random string in both loop controllers.

[image: Random String Demo]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) articles series for more information on the above and other functions.